# Who is responsible for damage in a furnished apartment?

Tags: germany

Suppose one lives in a furnished apartment, and after some time of living in it, damage comes up of normal wear and tear, then would the renter be liable for this, or would it be up to the landlord?

Comment: Is it damage or is it wear and tear? When something breaks through age (worn out) it isn't 'damaged' but 'broken'. You rental agreement probably sets out the liabilities, and the inventory should state the condition of each item of furniture at the time you rented it.

Comment: @WeatherVane In either case it is _legally_ damage, § 249 Ⅰ BGB.

Answer (score 6):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

The landlord is almost certainly liable for fair wear and tear. Although I wasn't able to find an authoritative source for this rule, it is fairly universally applied by the Courts and tenancy deposit arbitration schemes. While a landlord could try to draft a contract which shifts liability to the tenant, this would risk being caught by the [Unfair Terms in Consumer Contract Regulations 1999](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1999/2083/contents). See for example paragraph 4.52 of the [Office of Fair Trading's Guidance on unfair terms in tenancy agreements](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5a82d33ae5274a2e8ab598aa/oft356.pdf):

> We take the view that in short fixed term agreements, such as one for
> a year or less, a standard term making the tenant liable to redecorate
> the property regardless of whether the tenant has done something to
> make it necessary may be regarded as unfair. The potential effect of
> such a term is to require tenants to return the property in a better
> condition than that in which they received it and for landlords to
> benefit considerably at the tenants' expense. We do not object to
> terms requiring tenants to redecorate or pay for redecoration where
> they have caused deterioration to the décor at the property beyond
> what could be described as fair wear and tear.

Answer (score 5):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Quoting § 535 BGB:

> § 535 Inhalt und Hauptpflichten des Mietvertrags
> (1) Durch den Mietvertrag wird der Vermieter verpflichtet, dem Mieter den Gebrauch der Mietsache während der Mietzeit zu gewähren. Der Vermieter hat die Mietsache dem Mieter in einem zum vertragsgemäßen Gebrauch geeigneten Zustand zu überlassen **und sie während der Mietzeit in diesem Zustand zu erhalten**.

Translation:

> § Section 535 Content and main obligations of the tenancy agreement
> (1) The rental agreement obliges the landlord to grant the tenant the use of the rented property during the rental period. The landlord must leave the rented property to the tenant in a condition suitable for use in accordance with the contract **and maintain it in this condition during the rental period**.

Apartments with furniture are a little bit of a new thing in Germany. It was customary to rent out unfurnished apartments and lay all the problems with furniture on the tenant. That is still possible. However, apartments with furniture can be rented out above the market maximum rent that would be allowed. So it has caught on in Germany.

I am saying this because this "exception to be able to go above the allowed rent" is exactly *because* the landlord is responsible for repairing or replacing all damage or defects, unless they were intentional or negligent. And since the landlord is supposed to incur regular costs, not just the one-time cost of buying furniture, they are allowed to charge more rent per month.

If you are renting an apartment complete with furniture, you are already paying more per month, to make up for the regular repair and replacement of broken things. I will assume your landlord has not waived this opportunity out of the goodness of their heart and sympathy for their tenant.

Not only are they required to do this, it is also not allowed to specify anything to the contrary in the individual contract. Those clauses are invalid.

If you *do* have to pay for something, because it was intentional or negligent, you should make sure you are not paying more than required. So for example if you broke a 10 year old TV because you were angry about your team losing the championship and threw the remote at it, you have to pay for a replacement. However, the cost is calculated depending on the previous TV and how old it was; the landlord cannot just have you buy a brand new TV to replace their old TV, since their old TV would have been worth way less.

Comment: Note that the 'this condition' that has to be maintained refers to the 'condition suitable for use' in the previous sentence. It does not imply that the condition of the furniture should remain constant, it can suffer wear and tear.

Comment: Yes indeed. so for example they don't have to buy a new TV every year just so it's always a new TV, they just have to repair or replace it, in case it breaks and stops being a TV as described in the contract.

Answer (score 0):

> […] would the renter be liable for this, or would it be to the landlord?

The primary source to answer such a question is always *the contract*.
If German jurisdiction is applicable, you can assess the answer based on following scheme:

1. Damages
   Landlord L could have a claim against renter R for damages for damage present in object O amounting to € 10<sup>†</sup> according to §§ 280 Ⅰ, Ⅲ, 281 BGB.

   1. Relationship with obligations (*Schuldverhältnis*)
      (+) L and R concluded a now terminated contract that can be characterized as a tenancy agreement as per §§ 549 ff. BGB.
   2. Breach of duty (*Pflichtverletzung*)
      R must have breached one of his duties.
      A breach of duty is any objective deviation from the contractually owed duties.
      The tenancy agreement states R has to return the apartment’s keys and furniture, including object O.
      However, the agreement does not say *in which condition* O is to be returned.
      The agreement needs to be construed in accordance to §§ 133, 157.

      - The agreement does not contain any provisions regarding a damage of O.<sup>†</sup>
        Apparently the parties did not anticipate such a case.
      - This might be the case because object O is a durable good<sup>†</sup> and such *not* susceptible to damage.
        It is designed to withstand use of at least 3 years.<sup>†</sup>
        A damage is therefore unlikely.
      - Object O is/was already assembled.
        In its assembled configuration O is difficult to move (between apartments).
        Such a stationary use minimizes risk of damage even further.

      Therefore the parties agreed object O is to be returned in its same condition as at the beginning of the renting period.
      Since a damage of O was registered, R deviated from his owed duties, thus a breach of duties is present.
   3. Causation (*Kausalität*)
      (+) § 249 Ⅰ, without the breach of duties there would not have been any damage.
   4. Responsibility (*Vertretenmüssen*)
      In general, § 276 Ⅰ 1, responsible for damage caused intentionally or by negligence.
      However, normal wear and tear excluded, [§ 538](http://Bundesrecht.Juris.de/bgb/__538.html).

      1. Alteration (*Veränderung oder Verschlechterung*)
         (+) Object O displays alterations.
      2. Through use (*Gebrauch*)
         (+) The alterations can be attributed to use.
      3. According to contract (*verträgsgemäß*)
         The contract does not stipulate how object O is supposed to be used, hence the contract needs to be construed in line with §§ 133, 157.

         L provided object O *with* the apartment.
         It is therefore reasonable to presume that both parties agreed to the conditions:

         - O is to be used primarily by one person (usually R himself),
         - primarily in the apartment,
         - for purposes O is designed for (e. g. sitting if it is a chair).

         The observed alterations match aforesaid conditions.
         Normal wear and tear is therefore present.
      4. intermediate result
         (−) no responsibility
   5. intermediate result
      (−) no damages
2. Result
   Landlord L does not have a claim against R for damages.

<sub><sup>†</sup>:
Fictitious figure/facts not present in the question.</sub>

---

Notes:

- Tenancy agreements are typically *long‑term* contracts.
  You see the change of laws.
  You should therefore also ask the question:
  Which law (version) is applicable?